# Ag-grid angular-material-theme

Tags: angular, sass, ag-grid

I've included the new material theme (ag-theme-material) and encounterd a problem, which is, that the "$ag-mat-accent" variable is ignored completely. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved using $primary-color and $accent-color instead of $ag-mat-primary and $ag-mat-accent.

Comment: I've changed my variables to $primary-color and $accent-color but it is still not working. By the way, even the default colors are not working.